# Linking cells in a row so that the rows can be sorted by date which is in one of the cells of each row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in cells in rows in excel.  One cell in each row contains a date.  I want to sort the worksheet rows by date and have the data in the row stay connected to the date of that row and have the whole row move together as the rows are sorted by date.

Comment: What you've described is standard functionality of Excel. Do you get different result? Please post sample data and screenshot of the issue.

Comment: [How to sort a column but keep intact rows in Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2977-excel-sort-column-but-keep-rows.html)

Comment: If you sort using Date column then Excel automatically pull related data in other columns accordingly,, use CUSTOM SORT & select entire data set !

Comment: Slicer can link sever columns data and sort.

Answer (score 0):

- Select all data you consider related, together with its headings.
- Press CTRL-SHIFT-L to activate AutoFilter.
- Then go to the heading of your date-column and click the tiny button with a down pointing triangle,
- select the option to sort according to your wishes in the menu.

At this point you have other advanced options too, e.g. filtering one column, then adding a filter to more columns having those affect the result.